# Establing connection to MYSQL Database [PHP]

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, database, server

I had this random question in my mind while I was surfing on the net...

Is it possible to establish connection to MYSQL database WITHOUT refreshing? Like if there is a button in a page which when clicked it secretly establishes connection to Database without even letting user notice any change in the webpage, Everything looks the same but secretly a webpage connects to the database..

I know.. This process is possible in Javascript, but I wanted to find out a way in PHP

Comment: php runs in server side not in client side. one thing maybe done if you trigger that button with auto click and send via ajax to server

Comment: +U_mulder Yeah. I had this random question like suddenly and couldn't find a solution for it.

Comment: Not without AJAX, which of course is javascript

Comment: Even you won't know the connection has been established unless you explicitly emailed to your inbox the status :D

Comment: It's interesting that you'd imagine a website having a button which to the user would appear to do absolutely nothing.

Comment: @jonju Yeah but if any error occured I could possibly print the error out so the user gets to know that something is wrong I guess.. I am completely new to Web development.

Comment: @apokryfos Nope.. Actually I imagined that it would print out the database stat later on.. (I was actually imagining something like button clickers which when clicked will establish connection to the db and add +1 to the stored value of Clicks)

Comment: @Akshit..that means connection not established.

Comment: @AkshitSharma That's not a secret then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the page has been loaded. PHP can't be used anymore because it's a server side language. Javascript on the other hand works client side. Which means you can execute functions and such on the client's machine **without page reload**.

AJAX can enable you to 'open' a PHP and execute PHP code (not JS) without page reload. If you will, it's like you're opening a PHP page but it's not visible to the user, it runs the PHP file 'behind'.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, remember that PHP is a "server-side" language, and that the SQL database also lives on the "server side." The JavaScript application, running on the client, has no direct access to it.

What the JavaScript application must do, then, is to *issue asynchronous requests* ("AJAX ...") to the server, asking for whatever it wants.  The end-user will not be directly aware that this is going on, and the content of the screen-display won't necessarily change (unless you change it).

As part of servicing the *(properly authorized ...)* request, the PHP side might connect to the database and issue queries against it to get the information that it needs, in order to prepare and send-back a reply to the (JavaScript) client.

Now, the JavaScript side won't necessarily *know,* nor will it *care,* just **how** the results that it receives were actually obtained by the PHP code. It only "issues a request, and, sometime thereafter, gets a corresponding answer."